# Fieldset odd alignment/padding/margin issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

This issue is driving me nuts. There is a small chance that I've simply missed something, but after a half day of face-palming I obviously need someone to find and explain this  issue, or correct my mistake.

I've created a small example of my problem in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTwhN/), but it's probably only reproducable if you use Chrome. I'll try to explain anyhow:

My fieldset is right aligning within a section, or adding some 300px margin-left style. But I've checked the outputted code, and computed styles, and nothing jumps out as strange to me. **The strangest thing is that if I add a border in the "section" (border: 1px solid #000) the fieldset suddenly aligns correctly.**

The HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="page">
    <header>
        <div id="title">
             <h1>The System</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="logindisplay">
            Welcome <strong><a href="#" id="userdetails">Username</a></strong>! [ <a href="/Account/LogOff">Log Off</a> ]
        </div>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Patient">Patients</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Report">Reports</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Printouts">Printouts</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Account/AdminIndex">Admin</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/Account/SysAdminIndex">SysAdmin</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section id="main">
            <fieldset class="headline">
                <legend class="headline">Patients</legend>
                    <p>Why is this aligned right?</p>
                    <input id="button-add-patient" type="button" value="Add a new patient" />
            </fieldset>
    </section>
    <footer>Blahblah</footer>
</div>
</body>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #5c87b2;
    font-size: 68%;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #696969;
    min-width: 600px;
}

p, ul {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
}
header, footer, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
/* HEADINGS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* PRIMARY LAYOUT ELEMENTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/

 .page {
    width: 96%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1270px;
    min-width: 600px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
header, #header {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0;
}
header h1, #header h1 {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #111;
}
#main {
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
footer, #footer {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #CCC;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    font-size: .9em;
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}
/* TAB MENU
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 ul#menu {
    padding: 0 0 4px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li a {
    padding: 7px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: #ececec;
    color: #45709a;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
}
ul#menu li a:active {
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#menu li.selected a {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
/* FORM LAYOUT ELEMENTS
----------------------------------------------------------*/
 fieldset {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1em 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
legend {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
fieldset.headline {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 1em 1.4em 1.4em 1.4em;
    margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
legend.headline {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

/* TABLE
----------------------------------------------------------*/
table {
    border: solid 1px #aaaaaa;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-size: 1em;
}
table td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: solid 1px #aaaaaa;
}
table th {
    padding: 6px 5px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    border: solid 1px #aaaaaa;
}

/* MISC
----------------------------------------------------------*/

nav, #menucontainer {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
div#title {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}
#logindisplay {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 10px 0 5px 10px;
    color: White;
}

#logindisplay a:link {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

The odd fix (replace existing main-section):

```
<section id="main" style="border:1px solid #000">
```

Since I couldn't find anything on SO or Google about this issue I'm prepared to assume that I've simply made a mistake in my CSS/Html. But then again IE seems to render it ok...

Edit:

Adding a screendump on my output, with Chrome (Version 32.0.1700.107 m) for Windows:

[image: Screendump from jsFiddle]

Comment: I don't see the problem in Chrome 32 on Mac OS X. Unless I misunderstood the problem :)

Comment: Ah, I'll add a screendump of my output

Comment: Definitely not seeing the problem on Mac OS X, but booting Win8 in Parallels on the same machine shows the problem in the same Chrome version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s because of your `#title` element, that is floated to the left – and therefor floats *out* of the `header` element.

Move the cursor over the `#title` element in the DOM inspector, and you see from the highlighting within the page that it reaches into the white background of the section.

If you remove the `padding-bottom` from the `h1` within `#title`, it fits.

Or add `overflow:hidden` to your `header` element, so that it will contain the float. (That’ll make the title move up visually though.)

(There’s of course other ways of fixing this as well, it depends on what exactly you want.)

Comment: Nice catch. Tried overflow: hidden and it seems to have fixed the issue. Any idea why the #title element floats out of the header? I mean, a negative margin och position I would get, but shouldn't the header contain the title as it is witten now?

Comment: I guess the combination of float and a line-height of 2em wasn't the greatest. I now set the line-height in pixels instead, but the overflow protection will have to stay just in case :-)

Comment: Floated elements do in general not influence the height of their parent – unless special conditions are met, like the parent is floated itself or has `overflow` set to something other than the default `visible`.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this addition to fieldset.headline:

```
min-width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Here is updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FTwhN/6/).

In last time Chrome becomes worse than IE :)